# Open source JMAP compliant servers?

Tags: email, email-client, jmap

I'm exploring the possibility of building a centrally hosted email client, embedded within my site. Users would be provisioned a new email address from me, they are not using their existing email. Essentially, I'm looking for the feature set of an email web client (multiple user accounts, get inbox messages, read, delete, compose new, organize, etc) exposed as set of RESTful APIs. A brief web search uncovered very little meeting my desires, but I did come across http://jmap.io. I was unable to find an existing implementation of the specification that I could leverage for my solution, and would love to avoid writing my own. Are there any existing solutions (JMAP or otherwise) that might meet my needs? I've ruled out https://context.io/ because I cannot have the emails stored or consumed by a third party.

Comment: Until a JAMP open source server arrives, you can use the open source JMAP [proxy](https://proxy.jmap.io/) together with an open source IMAP server.

Answer (score 4):

I'm actively contributing to the Apache James Server. As part of my work, I am working on a JMAP implementation with my co-workers.

So far, we are able to build a working web-mail on top of it in one of our company product, OpenPaas.

And as it is an Apache project, it is OpenSource. Maybe you want to have a look...

https://github.com/apache/james-project/tree/master/server/protocols/jmap

http://james.apache.org/

Answer (score 2):

[Stalwart JMAP server](https://github.com/stalwartlabs/jmap-server) was just released (September 2022) and it includes full support for JMAP Core, JMAP Mail and JMAP over WebSocket. Support for JMAP Contacts and Calendar will be added as soon as these become IETF standards.

Answer (score 1):

I just want to add that as for now (2020) Cyrus IMAP also has JMAP support.